# How to display a search bar in Google search result

Tags: html

After a search in Google, I saw that some website result display also a search bar after their first result where the user can search their website like on the image below

[image: 1]

Now please how to do that ? Is there an html code that we have to add to our pages ?

Comment: No. Google will decide if they want to include this and it is usually reserved for very popular sites that clearly rank well for a search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by following the instructions in this page : https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview

I think this solves your problem. While it is somehow technical, this is the solution.

Comment: how much time google will take to bring the search box in search results? As i indexed my site around 20 days back, still its not reflected and there are no errors in my code as per google webmasters. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know. In general you should have patient with SEO and stuff that has to do with Google.