# How to add a search bar to Google search results?

Tags: html, search, google-search-console

*I didnt find the answer on this link : [How to display a search bar in Google search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724258/how-to-display-a-search-bar-in-google-search-result)*

I have a site with a search bar, and I'm trying to make it look **like this** when I send it to google.

[image: image-for-search-bar]

I read the Google documents, but I couldn't find them. Can someone help?

Comment: If image unseen : https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/11/22/RS7YDM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could try to describe it, but I guess, the google-text is far better than me:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox

Comment: You are awesome! Thank u much <3